# Rails Assets precompile is too slow ~12hrs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am local precompile assets [like this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#local-precompilation)
 **RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile**, but it's too slows 12hrs. I don't know what happen! and I don't  know how to start to do something.
Also when I make changes in some stylesheet files, these delay around 10s

Please anyone can help me, thanks!

This is my applications.css.scss

```scss
@import "_font-awesome";
@import "jquery.ui.core";
@import "jquery.ui.theme";
@import "dataTables/src/demo_table_jui";
@import "token-input-facebook";
@import "fullcalendar";
@import "fullcalendar.print";

@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap-multiselect";
@import "bootstrap-datetimepicker";

@import "header";
@import "sub_header";
@import "students";
@import "people";
@import "institutions";
```

My Gemfile:

```Gemfile
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.0.3.0'
```

its versions:

```
bootstrap-sass (3.0.3.0)
sass (3.2.12)
sass-rails (3.2.6)
```

Additional info:

```
rails 3.2.16
ruby 1.9.3
```

**UPDATE1**

[My complete Gemfile](http://pastebin.com/BSbadzrj)

**UPDATE2**

When I put disable the assets compress `config.assets.compress = false`,in production mode, I get it results:

```shell
real    5m13.113s
user    5m5.355s
sys     0m5.268s
```

**UPDATE3**

got improvement but not a solution.

- I change the **css_compresor**, now I'm using `:yui`.
- I change `application.css.scss` in favor to use Sprockets require directives.

Now this is my [application.css.scss file](http://pastebin.com/rWiBeMRT).

The time to precompile it's : **~24min**

Comment: **12 hours**, Seriously?

Comment: Can you give us the whole Gemfile, please?

Comment: @marvelousNinja http://pastebin.com/BSbadzrj

Comment: I don't know if this has anything to do with it, admittedly, but do you have some particularly large files in your asset folders (images and or other non-css/js assets)? Also, what does your memory and CPU usage look like when its precompiling? Is there a lot of swaping, etc going on?

Comment: I don't have any large files in my assets. The status-cpu while I'm compiling  the assets is: cpu: %56, ram: 1.3/2.8 and swap: 1.3mb/1.8gb and also I try it in another cpus but I had the same problem.

Comment: Try deploying to heroku.  When you do a git push it will compile your assets.  This will test if the problem lies in your machine or your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem:

The problem was the use of `@extend` sentence in my .scss files. 
This problem appear in this sass version.

I wanted more semantic html files([READ HERE](http://www.sitepoint.com/sass-semantically-extend-bootstrap/) for more information about it).

I found this problem making introspection into Sprockets precompile. With [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/asset-precompile-works-part/) great tutorial

The solution is take off all `@extend` sentences from my scss files and use plain bootstrap in my html.

Example: I had to change this.

```html
# main.html
<div class='user-information'> ... </div>
```

```css
# main.scss
.user-information {
  @extend .col-md-12
}
```

by this:

```html
# main.html
<div class='col-md-12'> ... </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out, the root of your problem may be similar (i.e. @import is slow): https://gist.github.com/noniq/1746744

We had asset compilation times of 7mins on the fastest i7 Macbook Pro. Using the above hack reduced it to just over 2mins. Turns out our use of compass was poor and the even better  solution was to only import it where necessary and only import the specific parts of compass we needed in a given scss partial. Even an empty scss file that was importing compass took about 2 seconds to compile, and since we had many, many partials, it added up.